# Javascript CSS visability

Tags: javascript, css

It seems that javascript only can ready inline css if i want to check if element is display:hidden getting it with:

```
el.style.display
```

But how to check if display:none is placed inside external CSS file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to access the computed style of the element with `getComputedStyle` (standards-compatible browsers) or `currentStyle` (IE). Google for those terms for examples or use a framework such as jQuery, which provide wrappers for that.

Comment: I confirm that getComputedStyle and currentStyle is a perfectly working solution. Just detect IE with condition and thats it.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It might be the backwards way and not helpful in this case, but anyway:

If you want to check out what's in the loaded CSS files, you can get the loaded stylesheets with `var sheets = document.styleSheets;`, and access the first one with `sheets[0];`
Then, get the rules from it:

```
var rules = sheets[0].cssRules ? sheets[0].cssRules : sheets[0].rules;
```

Then loop through the rules to check them out:

```
var rule, selector;
for (var idx=0, len=rules.length; idx<len; ++idx) {
  rule = rules[idx];
  selector = rule.selectorText;
  if (!selector) {continue;}
  console.log(selector+' => '+ rule.style.cssText);
}
```

This is more or less straight from David Flanagan's great book "Javascript, the Definitive Guide (5th ed.)"

Answer (score 0):

`if(el.style.display=='none')` will work regardless of where the CSS is defined.

Comment: Actually it doesn't. `element.style` contains *only* anything that is set in the style attribute.